# integrating ccavenue payment gateway in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am trying to integrate ccavenue payment gateway in my rails app..But I cant find any proper documentation. All they provide is 4 files for the integration. I cant figure out how to fit all these together.

**1) ccavRequestHandler.html.erb**

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<%
  merchantData=""
  working_key=""   #Put in the 32 Bit Working Key provided by CCAVENUES.  
  access_code=""   #Put in the Access Code in quotes provided by CCAVENUES.

  params.each do |key,value|
      merchantData += key+"="+value+"&" 
  end

  crypto = Crypto.new
  encrypted_data = crypto.encrypt(merchantData,working_key)

%>
  <iframe  width="482" height="500" scrolling="No" frameborder="0"  id="paymentFrame" src="https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction&encRequest=<%=encrypted_data %>&access_code=<%=access_code %>"></iframe>
</center>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('iframe#paymentFrame').load(function() {
         window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
             $("#paymentFrame").css("height",e.data['newHeight']+'px');    
         }, false);
       }); 
      });
  </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

**2) ccavResponseHandler.html.erb**

```
<html>
<head>  
  <title>Response Handler</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags%>
</head>
<body>
<%  
  workingKey=""#Put in the 32 Bit Working Key provided by CCAVENUES.   
  encResponse=params[:encResp]
  crypto = Crypto.new 
  decResp=crypto.decrypt(encResponse,workingKey);
  decResp = decResp.split("&")
%>
<center>
    <font size="4" color="blue"><b>Response Page</b></font>
    <table border="1">
<tr>
  <td><b>Parameter Name</b></td>
  <td><b>Parameter Value</b></td>

  <%decResp.each do |key|%> 
    <tr>
      <td><%=key.from(0).to(key.index("=")-1)%> </td>
      <td><%=key.from(key.index("=")+1).to(-1)%> </td>
    </tr>
  <%end%>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**3) crypto.rb**

```
#*****************************************************************
#           * COMPANY    - AVENUES INDIA PVT Ltd.,
#*****************************************************************

#Name of the Program : AES Encryption/Decryption
#Created by          : AVENUES INDIA PVT Ltd., TC-Team
#Created On          : 16-02-2014
#Version             : Version 1.0
#Contribution       : eLitmus Evaluation Pvt Ltd
#***************************************************************** 



class Crypto < ActiveRecord::Base

  INIT_VECTOR = (0..15).to_a.pack("C*")    

  def encrypt(plain_text, key)
      secret_key =  [Digest::MD5.hexdigest(key)].pack("H*") 
      cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-128-cbc')
      cipher.encrypt
      cipher.key = secret_key
      cipher.iv  = INIT_VECTOR
      encrypted_text = cipher.update(plain_text) + cipher.final
      return (encrypted_text.unpack("H*")).first
  end

  def decrypt(cipher_text,key)
      secret_key =  [Digest::MD5.hexdigest(key)].pack("H*")
      encrypted_text = [cipher_text].pack("H*")
      decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-128-cbc')
      decipher.decrypt
      decipher.key = secret_key
      decipher.iv  = INIT_VECTOR
      decrypted_text = (decipher.update(encrypted_text) + decipher.final).gsub(/\0+$/, '')
      return decrypted_text
  end
end
```

**4) dataForm.html.erb**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" name="customerData" action="/transaction/ccavRequestHandler">
        <table width="40%" height="1" border='1' align="center"><caption><font size="4" color="blue"><b>Integration Kit</b></font></caption></table>
            <table width="40%" height="100" border='1' align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>Parameter Name:</td><td>Parameter Value:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"> Compulsory information</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Merchant Id :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_id" value="2954"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Order Id    :</td><td><input type="text" name="order_id" value="123654789"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Amount  :</td><td><input type="text" name="amount" value="1.00"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Currency    :</td><td><input type="text" name="currency" value="INR"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Redirect URL    :</td><td><input type="text" name="redirect_url" value="http://merchantdomain/transaction/ccavResponseHandler"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cancel URL  :</td><td><input type="text" name="cancel_url" value="http://merchantdomain/transaction/ccavResponseHandler"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Language    :</td><td><input type="text" name="language" value="EN"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Billing information(optional):</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Billing Name    :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_name" value="Charli"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Billing Address :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_address" value="Room no 1101, near Railway station Ambad"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Billing City    :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_city" value="Indore"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Billing State   :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_state" value="MP"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Billing Zip :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_zip" value="425001"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Billing Country :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_country" value="India"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Billing Tel :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_tel" value="9876543210"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Billing Email   :</td><td><input type="text" name="billing_email" value="person@gmail.com"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Shipping information(optional)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shipping Name   :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_name" value="Chaplin"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shipping Address    :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_address" value="room no.701 near bus stand"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>shipping City   :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_city" value="Hyderabad"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>shipping State  :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_state" value="Andhra"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>shipping Zip    :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_zip" value="425001"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>shipping Country    :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_country" value="India"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shipping Tel    :</td><td><input type="text" name="delivery_tel" value="9595226054"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Merchant Param1 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param1" value="additional Info."/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Merchant Param2 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param2" value="additional Info."/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Merchant Param3 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param3" value="additional Info."/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Merchant Param4 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param4" value="additional Info."/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Merchant Param5 :</td><td><input type="text" name="merchant_param5" value="additional Info."/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Promo Code  :</td><td><input type="text" name="promo_code" value=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Vault Info. :</td><td><input type="text" name="customer_identifier" value=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Integration Type    :</td><td><input type="text" name="integration_type" value="iframe_normal"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td><td><INPUT TYPE="submit" value="CheckOut"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

These 4 files is the only docs they provides..

I can also see that in html.erb file they want us to put the keys?? Is it safe??
The gem they provide is really outdated and hence didnt even mention about it.. I really cant figure out where to start with this..Can someone give me a rough idea on how to do this???

Comment: Were you able to figure this out

Comment: Any solution to this? I need to integrate this on a Rails 2.3.8 application.

Comment: @priyasaini should work..before finding a solution i moved to another payment gateway